# forward request to controller action

Tags: silverstripe

i'd like to forward a request to a controller to some specific action without redirecting to another url.

so, for example, the following url:
**/home/peter**
should internally become
**/home/people/peter**

i know i could catch the action name ('peter') in the 'init' function, then do a Controller::redirect, but i'd like to stay on the same url, just have the request internally forwarded to the 'people' action.

2 things to note:

- 'peter' is a dynamic string, so i can't just hardcode a route for this
- any other action of the controller shall still work, so only a couple of strings should get forwared (eg. 'peter', 'ann' get forwarded to the 'people' action, whereas 'otherAction' is still callable)

i already found the 'handleAction' and 'handleRequest' methods in the Controller class, but just can't imagine how make use of them for my task.

SilverStripe version: 3.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the use of `static $url_handlers` described [here](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/controller#url-handling), that allows you to define specific routes to actions. Your use case could be achieved by using a catch-all url-handler.

But therefore we have to pay attention to the order of each route. The catch-all route has to be defined at the end. All other actions need a seperate url handler before:

```
public static $url_handlers = array(
    'otherAction' => 'otherAction',
    // ...
    'people/$Name' => 'people',
    '$Name' => 'people' // catch-all
);
```

This should fit to your explanation. The last route catches all dynamic routes which weren't handled before.

But as Ingo mentioned, both routes would deliver the same content and that could be bad for SEO. You could target the second route `people/$Name` to a different action which does a 301 redirect to the url with `$Name` only. I would recommend this if you already have public content and you want to replace the existing URLs with the short version.

I hope this solves your problem (temporarily).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I assume you have good reasons for making duplicate URLs (bad for SEO) :)

I've tried around a bit with `Director::direct()`, which would be the cleanest, but didn't get anywhere. `Director::test()` resets most request state, so doesn't qualify either.
Calling `handleRequest()` or `handleAction()` on a new controller instance is tricky, because the `Director` has built up a lot of state by that time already (for example pushed to the controller stack).

So, unfortunately the SilverStripe routing isn't that flexible, anything you do will go deep into system internals, and potentially break with the next release.

Comment: thanks for sharing some insights here, fortunately Stefan's 'catch all' approach did the trick for me.